# What was the right choice for Zep Hindle to make in SAW?

Tags: plot-explanation, saw

In *Saw* Zep Hindle was told he had to kill a mother and her child to get the antidote or else he would die. He hadn't much of a choice then but becoming a murder, but Jigsaw always said he doesn't approve murder so what happened there? What was Zep supposed to do before Jigsaw's eyes then? If he really was supposed to commit murder, then how is this reconcilable with Jigsaw's views on murder?

Comment: Seems **opinion based** too me.

Comment: @Paulie_D He clearly seems to ask about *what Jigsaw expected* him to do.

Comment: *"Right"*.....seems to require an opinion. But (without knowledge of the franchise) I would assume *suicide*?

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, the opinion of a fictional character explored in the film and thus deducible from his actions and dialogue.

Answer (score 3):

Zep was abducted due to the his inferiority complex, which caused him to generally despise the people who were more successful than him, according to [this](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/Zep%27s_Test). From the [wiki](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/Zep_Hindle):

> Five months later Zep was abducted by the Jigsaw Killer, whom he didn't know was actually John Kramer. John poisoned him and left him a tape which provided instructions for Zep and told him that in order to get an antidote which could save his life he had to kidnap Alison and Diana Gordon, Dr. Gordon's wife and daughter, and had to hold them hostage while Gordon was forced by Jigsaw to play a game on his own. Furthermore he had to kill Gordon's family if the latter didn't pass his test by killing his cellmate, Adam Stanheight, by six o'clock.

I would wager that Jigsaw was expecting Gordon to kill Adam. This way, Zep would not have to kill anyone, just hold them hostage and then release them. Unless the Gordon family was guilty of something, there would be no point in killing them.

However, there's also the option of an **ill-conceived plot point**...

Comment: I'd go with the second option, considering Gordon had to murder someone in order for Zep to avoid murdering someone.

Comment: But Gordon was murdering a criminal, was he not? Adam was some sort of voyeur, or something?

Comment: But that would still imply having some of his subjects to murder somebody which contradicts Jigsaw's character. In fact many of his games require that: Amanda killing her cell mate, Art killing his, the insurance guy killing his employees, etc. I think its a big plot hole.

Comment: @CainNuke It's not so much a plot hole as a character flaw.  He's a hypocrite.  Jigsaw claims to operate by a code of ethics, but he only follows that code when it's suitable to his purposes. The fact that people always seem to do exactly what he expected them to do in his intricate schemes no doubt serves to inflate his ego and justify his decisions in this regard (in his own mind at least.)